# Why is this simple function not working?

Tags: r, function

I first defined new variable `x`, then created function that require `x` within its body (not as argument). See code below

```r
x <- c(1,2,3)
f1 <- function() {
  x^2
}

rm(x)

f2 <- function() {
  x <- c(1,2,3)
  f1()
}

f(2)  
Error in f1() : object 'x' not found
```

When I removed `x`, and defined new function `f2` that first define `x` and then execute `f1`, it shows objects `x` not found.

I just wanted to know why this is not working and how I can overcome this problem. I do not want `x` to be name as argument in `f1`.

Please provide appropriate title because I do not know what kind of problem is this.

Comment: Variable names are searched along the environment "chain" (`parent.env`). `x` declared within of `f2` is not in any parent environment but in "sibling" environment. Please read http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Environments.html for the basics to understand this problem in detail

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short: Your are expecting dynamic scoping but are a victim of R's lexical scoping:

- dynamic scoping = the enclosing environment of a command is determined during run-time
- lexical scoping = the enclosing environment of a command is determined at "compile time"

To understand the lookup path of your variable `x` in the current and parent environments try this code.

It shows that both functions do not share the environment in with `x` is defined in `f2` so it can't never be found:

```
# list all parent environments of an environment to show the "search path"
parents <- function(env) {
  while (TRUE) {
    name <- environmentName(env)
    txt <- if (nzchar(name)) name else format(env)
    cat(txt, "\n")
    if (txt == "R_EmptyEnv") break
    env <- parent.env(env)
  }
}

x <- c(1,2,3)
f1 <- function() {
  print("f1:")
  parents(environment())
  x^2
}

f1()  # works
# [1] "f1:"
# <environment: 0x4ebb8b8> 
# R_GlobalEnv 
# ...

rm(x)

f2 <- function() {
  print("f2:")
  parents(environment())
  x <- c(1,2,3)
  f1()
}

f2()  # does not find "x"
# [1] "f2:"
# <environment: 0x47b2d18> 
# R_GlobalEnv
# ...
# [1] "f1:"
# <environment: 0x4765828> 
# R_GlobalEnv 
# ...
```

Possible solutions:

1. Declare `x` in the global environment (bad programming style due to lack of encapsulation)
2. Use function parameters (this is what functions are made for)
3. Use a closure if `x` has always the same value for each call of `f1` (not for beginners). See the other answer from @JohnColeman...

I strongly propose using 2. (add x as parameter - why do you want to avoid this?).

Comment: There's also the possibility to use the superassignment operator `x <<- c(1,2,3)` in `f2`. This is frowned upon, I know. Pointing it just out for completeness.

Answer (score 6):

You could use a [closure](https://www.r-bloggers.com/closures-in-r-a-useful-abstraction/) to make an `f1` with the desired properties:

```
makeF <- function(){
  x <- c(1,2,3)
  f1 <- function() {
    x^2
  }
  f1
}

f1 <- makeF()
f1() #returns 1 4 9
```

There is no `x` in the global scope but `f1` still knows about the `x` in the environment that it was defined in.